# no package pango found when build the firefox

Tags: firefox, pango

I am building the customized source code of firefox. When I am going to build the firefox, I am given following error regading the "no pango package error". How can I solve this error. [image]

Answer (score 6):

If you are using Ubuntu 18.04 or similar, try:

```
sudo aptitude install libpango1.0-dev
```

In ubuntu 16.04

```
sudo apt install libpango1.0-dev
```

[from](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Developer_guide/Build_Instructions/Simple_Firefox_build/Linux_and_MacOS_build_preparation#Requirements_for_Debian_Ubuntu_users)

Answer (score 0):

`sudo yum install 'pkgconfig(pango)'`

Should install the necessary packages.